# Installing Laravel on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel, laravel-4

I'm brand new to AWS and this has got me stumped. I'm trying to install Laravel 4 on an instance I have on EC2 running the AMI Linux package. I don't have a domain for this, just using the free tier and trying it out.

Laravel needs to have the laravel/public folder as the document root but I can't work out how to do this. I've read loads of things about the conf.d folder vhosts file httpd.conf file and I don't really understand how it all fits together.

Can someone help me and tell me how I can set my documnent root so that when i visit my Elastic IP address it loads up correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your LAMP stack set up?

Comment: HI @Makita yes that's all installed. I can get Laravel working but I'm just having to point the browser to laravel/public and obviously this is not ideal.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access your laravel app by server ip you need to edit your httpd.conf file (usually in /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd) and set the DocumentRoot option to the right directory.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
```

and then restart apache